# Create a development environment for Laravel in Docker

Tags: php, laravel, docker

I have a custom Laravel installation on my Ubuntu machine. As per Laravel's instructions however, I didn't use Homestead to spin up my app. Instead I installed the app using composer on my machine and then installed the dependencies and libraries as per the requirement.

Now I want to use another machine for development. How's it possible using Docker to package a replica of my machine's environment to create a container to be used on the other machine. I am new to Docker and haven't used it before for whatsoever reasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered using [Laravel Valet](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/valet)? It's a lot more light weight than Docker and Homestead and can spin up your projects almost instantaneously.

If you wish to persist with Docker then [Laradock](https://github.com/laradock/laradock) has probably figured out most of what you wish to use.

Comment: I am using ubuntu as my development machine. From the docs it seems Valet is for Mac OS. Laradock seems to be a good choice. I will give it a try. Just had a doubt, will I have to install all node dependencies again if I create the environment?

Comment: @SanketR check out Carlos Priego's [fork](https://github.com/cpriego/valet-ubuntu) for Linux Valet. In Docker I believe you can set mirroring so your filesystem is reflected in Docker, hence you should be able to share dependencies that already exist in your project.

Comment: @Barry Blade Do I need to have docker installed before I git clone Laradoc and proceed with installation or Laradoc does all at once? Also because I haven't used Docker before, however I want to set my local dev env on docker, will Laradoc work for any PHP projects (even those not based on Laravel)?

Comment: @Lykos you can git clone the repo after you have installed laradock. Usually you install laradock by git cloning that report as well..

Answer (score 2):

I created a [barebones Docker Compose repo](https://github.com/yahyazini/simple-laravel-docker)  that can be used for Laravel or as a LAMP Server and it comes with:

- Apache
- PHP
- MySQL
- Composer
- PHPMyAdmin

Most of the ones I came across are pretty bloated with stuff that I didn't need.